# Laplace Transform Convolution Theorem Applied to Functions without Transforms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

My differentials prof taught us the convolution theorem and applied it to a differential equation

$ay'' + by' + cy = e^{t^{2}}$

Then he transformed it  and left the transform as $L(e^{t^{2}}) = F(s)$

then changing it into $Y = \frac{F(s)}{G(s)}$ for some $G(s)$

following which he applied the convolution theorem to obtain the solution

What i don't understand is how can you work with the transform of some function using convolution theorem if the transform doesn't exist in the first place

Comment: Do you actually have more details so we can give a more specific answer? I am going to guess that there is either some sort of shifting or the convolution is taking away the points that cause the given $F(t)$ problems, but without further details, it is hard to say.

Comment: Yeah, the problem as stated is not well-posed. The LT of the driving function needs to be defined, which this one is not.

Comment: Well the left hand side in this case was all constants so let's just say  $Y = \frac{F(s)}{G(s)}$ and G(s) is $s^{2} + 1$ then he applies convolution so $$y =\int_0^t sin(t-x) e^{x^{2}}dx$$ and say this is a solution and it will work for any continuous function but he says he doesn't know why×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\}=f(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\}=F(s)$ , in fact those relations can be extended even $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ or $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}$ do not exist.

Moreover, I can also prove your professor did the particular result correctly.

According to the particular result your professor did, the full version of the general solution of the corresponding ODE done by [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_variation_of_parameters) is $y=C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+\sin t\int_0^te^{t^2}\cos t~dt-\cos t\int_0^te^{t^2}\sin t~dt$

Note that the general solution can also rewrite as

$y=C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+\sin t\int_0^te^{x^2}\cos x~dx-\cos t\int_0^te^{x^2}\sin x~dx$

$y=C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+\int_0^te^{x^2}(\sin t\cos x-\cos t\sin x)~dx$

$y=C_1\sin t+C_2\cos t+\int_0^te^{x^2}\sin(t-x)~dx$

Which is consistent to the particular result your professor did.

Comment: I accept that that result is correct but how do you show that this result holds in general since you operate on the undefined transform by dividing it through with a function and then apply convolution to it rather than performing a transform and antitransform.